# Firefox Webdriver fails with UnreachableBrowserException and blank Screen

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, firefox-driver

I am running webdriver 2.53.1 against firefox 45.9.0ESR on Redhat Linux 6.6. `FirefoxDriver` object gets created successfully and firefox launches with blank page (`about:blank`) as expected. But when I do the 'get' to open the url, it fails with `UnreachableBrowserException` with underlying cause as `org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:7055 failed to respond`.

**Preferences set for FirefoxProfile**

```
app.update.auto = false
app.update.enabled = false
app.update.silent = false
media.gmp-provider.enabled = false
webdriver.log.file = webdriver_debug.log
webdriver.firefox.logfile = firefox_browser.log
```

**My observations**

1. Browser is running and is not killed
2. Browser has webdriver addon added.
3. By 'netstat' I see webdriver listening on port 7055
4. Though I configured to dump firefox and webdriver logs, nothing gets dumped.

**What I tried so far**

1. Handling the exception and retrying does not help
2. The firefox is a tar ball extract. I tried removing the folder and extracting again, but that did not help either.
3. Used `navigate().to(url)` instead of `get(url)` but result is same.

NOTE: The JRE 7 is used for running

*Upgrading Selenium*
We cannot upgrade the selenium or firefox as there are many other dependent layers to be upgraded for selenium/firefox to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your jars files of selenium both server and client.

Download the latest jars from below link :-

http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

You also need to update your gecko driver from below URL :-

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Additionality update your firefox

Help -> About

Comment: I understand we are not using latest versions. Please note, that we cannot upgrade the selenium or firefox.  The issue here is tests work good 9 out of 10 times and suddenly in one run we see this failure in some random test.